# MSSQL2012 encrypt cells at user-level

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2012, encryption-asymmetric

Is there a way to encrypt cell values based on user account? So that:

- Only the valid users can decrypt the values of some cells?
- Or, a way to crypt data by user authentication, so only the right user will decrypt it?

For now this is my solution: I create asymmetric keys, and grant users on them. It's not good because:

1. I must create one key for each user or group of users;
2. It can't be atomic;
3. Query for read data must always retrieve key name.

Example:

```
create database test_for_encrypt
Go
use test_for_encrypt
Go

-- Create Master key and certificate
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'StrongPass1234';
CREATE CERTIFICATE MySelfSignedCert
WITH SUBJECT = 'MySelfSignedCert',
EXPIRY_DATE = '07/14/2020';

-- Create Asymmetric keys
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY Asym_user_1  WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY Asym_user_2  WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048

-- create table with data and select data
create table tb_encrypt (word nvarchar(100), asymkey nvarchar(100), crypt varbinary(1000))
Go
insert tb_encrypt (word, asymkey) values (N'One', N'Asym_user_1'), (N'Two', N'Asym_user_2')
update tb_encrypt set crypt = ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID(asymkey), word)
select word, crypt, convert(nvarchar, DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID(asymkey), crypt)) as decrypt
from tb_encrypt


-- create new user with grants
create login [user_asym] With password = N'password_1234'
CREATE USER [user_asym] FOR login [user_asym]
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[db_datareader] TO [user_asym]
GRANT CONTROL ON ASYMMETRIC KEY::[Asym_user_1] TO [user_asym]
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [user_asym]

-- After this, Logout and Login with [user_asym]
-- Select data with user [user_asym]
select word, crypt, convert(nvarchar, DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID(asymkey), crypt)) as decrypt
from tb_encrypt
```

Comment: What version of sql are you using? If you are playing with 2016 preview you should look at this feature. http://blogs.microsoft.com/next/2015/05/27/always-encrypted-sql-server-2016-includes-new-advances-that-keeps-data-safer/#sm.000n5aecc10nrfkuxaz24umzkk4q0

Comment: Version 2012. I'm going to update the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep a table with user names and whether the corresponding column is Encrypted for them or not.
Use a table valued function with the user as the parameter and based on the above table determine the columns to be Encrypted or not.

Something like:

```
Select Case when UserSeeEncrypted = 1 then <EncryptedVal>
Else <Decrypted> ....
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I add the following table

```
Create Table #Users (UserName varchar(100), IsEncrypted bit )
Insert into #Users
Select 'PrasadPC\Prasad', 1 -- this is my username for my machine (i used to test)
Union
Select 'user2', 0
Union
Select 'user3', 1

select * from #Users
```

This code is taken from your post and modified.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'StrongPass1234';
CREATE CERTIFICATE MySelfSignedCert
WITH SUBJECT = 'MySelfSignedCert',
EXPIRY_DATE = '07/14/2020';
```

the ASYMMETRIC KEY is one for any record

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [Encrypt_Key_Radioleao]  WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048
```

create table with data and select data (I changed your table structure
just to hold the word, if u need to keep the encrypted data, u can do 
that by changing my logic a bit)

```
create table #tb_encrypt (word nvarchar(100))
Go
insert #tb_encrypt (word) values (N'One'), (N'Two')
```

Now the Query

```
select Word,  
Case when exists
(Select UserName from #Users 
where IsEncrypted = 0 and SUSER_SNAME() = UserName ) then Word
Else 
convert(nvarchar(max), ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('Encrypt_Key_Radioleao'),
 Word)) End as En_Decrypt
from #tb_encrypt e

-- change My user to see decrypted data, 
Update #Users set IsEncrypted = 0  where UserName = 'PrasadPC\Prasad'
```

Comment: The OP asks how to simplify encryption, not how to determine that a field is encrypted

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
The question is:
Is there a way to encrypt cell values based on user account? 

So in my solution I'm telling something like the following:

    Select Case when UserSeeEncrypted = 1 then <EncryptedVal>
    Else <Decrypted> ....

I'll add this to the enswer

Comment: It suggest a way to the one who asked the question

Comment: the question is: if there is a user JOE, I need a data encypted in a way that only JOE could decypt it. This method must be valid for every user.